# Callback from new thread to class from which thread was initiated

Tags: java, multithreading, callback

I have a class from which I am calling a new thread.

```
public class MainClass{

 private void cleardata() {
                // do something on a separate thread
                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        //Do Something
        //After this I would like to notify my MainClass that some thing has been done and pass a value. 
        }
      }
     }
   private void callbackFunc(int a){

    // Do something based on value of a 
  }
}
```

I have a function in my MainClass. But how do i call this function from my new thread, so as to receive a callback.
Thanks.

Comment: If the method is in the same class as your thread you can just call it and pass your result.

Comment: Have you tried calling the operation from within run()

Comment: Do not confuse `Thread` and `Runnable`.

Comment: what is the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just be able to call the method in `MainClass` by its name just as if you were calling from directly inside `MainClass` itself (as opposed to from the inner class).

If a method name you want to call happens to conflict with one that your inner class has inherited from `Object` then you can prefix the call with `MainClass.this`, e.g. `MainClass.this.toString()` calls `toString` on `MainClass`, whereas just `toString()` calls it on the inner class instance.

Comment: Great thanks, one quick question. If the thread in from the same class, then even the private functions are accessible?

Comment: @Sunny yes, an inner class or static nested class is allowed to access all members of its containing class, even private ones. The `private` modifier limits access to the _lexical_ scope of the class body, which includes any other classes nested inside it.

Answer (score 0):

In such a case pass the instance of MainClass to the thread class ((during creation)) so that it can call method on it. Having inner class as suggested by others is also a good option.

Something similar-

```
class MainClass {

private void cleardata() {
    new Thread(new MyThread(this)).start();
}
```

}

class MyThread implements Runnable {

```
private MainClass mc;

MyThread(MainClass mc) {
    this.mc = mc;
}

public void run() {
    // do something
    // mc.someMethod();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainClass{

private void cleardata() {
        // do something on a separate thread
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                callBackFunc(result); 
            }
        }
}

private void callBackFunc(int a) {

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do it:

```
public class MainClass{

  private void cleardata() {
            // do something on a separate thread
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    //Do Something
                    notifyTheClass("a parameter");
     }
  }

  private void notifyTheClass(String aParam) {
  //..do something else
  }  
 }
}
```

But it is not related to threads, this is about inner classes. If you want the main thread to wait until the new thread is finishes, use [Futures](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) for a result. Or use some other multithreading primitives.